# How to produce a list of executables as a separate cmake target

Tags: c++, cmake

I tried my best to add a custom cmake target that compiles a list of .cpp files from a specific folder, and produces an executable for each file, with no success. Basically my scenario is as following:

```
foreach (FILE ${EXAMPLE_FILES})
    add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${FILE})
endforeach ()
```

Currently, when I type `cmake .. && make`, everything works fine, all those example files from the list `${EXAMPLE_FILES}` are compiled, and an executable produced for each. However, I'd like to remove this from the `make all` target, i.e., I'd like to produce those executables only when I type e.g. `make examples`. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: "However, I'd like to remove this from the `make all` target" - Add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` keyword to the [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) call. "I'd like to produce those executables only when I type e.g. `make examples`" - Create a custom target (with `add_custom_target`) named `examples` and make it dependent (with `add_dependencies`) from executables.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm, maybe write an answer so I can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` keyword to `add_executable` call, the building of the executable will be excluded from `make all`. For make a single target to create multiple executables just make this target *dependent* from these executables.

```
# Create the custom target before loop.
add_custom_target(examples)

foreach (FILE ${EXAMPLE_FILES})
    # Every executable target should have unique name.
    # E.g. if every example source is given in form '<name>.c'
    # Then we could use '<name>' as the executable target
    string(REPLACE ".c" "" TARGET_NAME "${FILE}")
    # Create an executable
    add_executable({$TARGET_NAME} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${FILE})
    # And make 'examples' to depend from that executable
    add_dependencies(examples ${TARGET_NAME})
endforeach ()
```